# 'object' doesn't contain a definition for 'keyCount'

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to coding and this script is giving me an error. It's suppose to pick up a key for a door.

It says it's error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'keyCount' and no accessible extension method 'keyCount' accepting a 1st argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried double checking the script and matching it up to a tutorial I was watching. still no affect. I don't know how to make a definition (Idk where to look to find that).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class keyitems
{
    public static int keyCount;
}
public class keyitem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public object GameVariables { get; private set; }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
            {
                GameVariables.keyCount += 2;
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to pick up a key to open a door. any help on this would be amazing.

Comment: Should `GameVariables` be of type `keyitems` instead of `object`?

Comment: Even that wouldn't work, given that `keyCount` is a *static* field. You could just use `keyItems.keyCount` - the value of `GameVariables` is irrelevant to it. (I'd also *strongly* advise you to learn about .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class keyitems
{
    public static int keyCount;
}
public class keyitem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public object GameVariables { get; private set; }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
            {
                keyitems.keyCount += 2;
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`keyCount` variable is `keyitems`'s variable. So, you can get it like this :

```
keyitems.keyCount
```

---

And, I recommend you to use camel case when typing class name.

For example : KeyItems ( not keyitems )